# How to get data, passed by a view composer to certain views, inside the controller?

Tags: php, laravel, view, controller

My View Composer passes some data to certain views (and it works, of course):

```
use Illuminate\View\View;
use App\Util\Helper

class PublicSettingsComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('settings', Helper::readSettingsFromFile()); // json
    }
}
```

---

The appropriate provider is added into the configuration and it provides this composer correctly for all specific views:

```
view()->compose('public.layouts.*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\PublicSettingsComposer');
```

---

However, inside (only) one of my views I need specific information from database, but therefore I have to use some data, that had been passed by my View Composer:

```
class BranchController extends Controller
{
    public function branches()
    {
        $settings = retrieve_settings_passed_by_PublicSettingsComposer; // This is what I need
        $headquartersId = $settings->headquartersid;
        return view('public.layouts.branches', [
            'headquarters' => Branch::find($headquartersId) // Branch is a Model
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

*FYI: Laravel version I'm using is: 5.5*

---

P.S. @moderators: *Please, be careful with considering my question as a duplicate. I know there are many questions about view composers and passing data to the views and grabbing data from within controllers. However, I really could not find any question with this context (titles are often misleading).*

Comment: Is there a particular reason you cannot simply use `Helper::readSettingsFromFile()` as used in the view composer in your controller as well?

Comment: At this moment I'm doing it that way. I just would like to know if there was a (better) way to avoid reading my file two times. So, I thought it could be possible to retrieve data, passed by a View Composer, within a controller.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with view composers, but I'd assume the file would also be read twice if you include the view composer in your controller manually and it is attached to the view automatically as well. Therefore my suggestion would be to use a singleton pattern or to cache the read data of `Helper::readSettingsFromFile()` before returning it. On concurrent method calls you could then just return the cached data. Just like you do with a singleton.

Comment: Thank you. Good idea. I thought about it as well. However, caching data is interesting only if I re-read data (update cache) after changes have been made to the file. Implementation of it is just a matter of time.

Comment: Well, how often does the file change? Maybe I can suggest you a very, very simple and quick solution.

Comment: Of course. How would you solve it? I would like to know it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two rather simple solutions for this. The first one is to cache the parsed file within each request. The other is to use an actual cache for this job.

The first option is very straight forward to implement. In your `Helper` class you'll have to introduce a static property to hold the parsed contents of the read file. Then, just like you do within the singleton pattern, you either return the cached data or you first parse the file, cache the data and return it afterwards. This scenario solves your actual problem of parsing the settings twice per requests if used in two places of your app.

```
class Helper
{
    protected static $cachedSettings;

    public function readSettingsFromFile()
    {
        if (!self::$cachedSettings) {
            self::$cachedSettings = // Do the parsing here. This should be your current implementation of Helper::readSettingsFromFile(). You can also put this in its own function.
        }

        return self::$cachedSettings;
    }
}
```

---

The other option is to use an actual cache (an external one). You can either cache the parsed file for a specific amount of times (like 1, 3, 5 or 10 minutes or even longer). Or you cache it forever and invalidate the cache when you update the settings (if this happens within your app and you *know* it was updated).

This solution does only make sense if your settings do not change too frequently though. It also depends a bit on the amount of requests you expect towards your app. If your settings change not too frequently (less than every *x minutes*) and your app is used frequently (multiple requests every *x minutes*), then it could be a viable solution.

```
class Helper
{
    public function readSettingsFromFile()
    {
        return Cache::remember(function () {
            $settings = // Put your current calculation here

            return $settings;
        }, 3 * 60); // 3 * 60 = 180 seconds
    }
}
```